# rails_admin gem Encoding::CompatibilityError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin

I just tried out `rails_admin` and I ran into problems when saving strings containing umlauts (e.g. "ü, ö, ä ..."). The model is saved to the database, but the follow up screen fails.

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Extracted source (around line #17):
```

```
14:   = menu_for((@abstract_model ? (@object.try(:persisted?) ? :member : :collection) : :root), @abstract_model, @object)
15:   = content_for :contextual_tabs
16: = yield
17: 
18: %footer
19:   %p © RailsAdmin 2012
```

I also tried to encode the string in utf8 using a before_save hook, but after pressing save the error is still there:

### My Model

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :img_small, ProductImgSmallUploader
  mount_uploader :img_large, ProductImgLargeUploader

  attr_accessible :img_small, :img_small_cache, :remove_img_small
  attr_accessible :img_large, :img_large_cache, :remove_img_large
  attr_accessible :title_de, :title_en, :description_de, :description_en, :visible

  before_save do
    [:title_de,:title_en,:description_de,:description_en].each do |arg|
      if self.try arg
        self.send("#{arg}=", self.send(arg).encode('UTF-8'))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it on my side? Or do i have to fork the gem?

### Full Stacktrace

```
rails_admin (0.1.2) app/views/layouts/rails_admin/pjax.html.haml:17:in `_c___uby____lib_ruby_gems_______gems_rails_admin_______app_views_layouts_rails_admin_pjax_html_haml___1061959050_34768032'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
haml (3.1.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:11:in `block in render_with_haml'
haml (3.1.7) lib/haml/helpers.rb:90:in `non_haml'
haml (3.1.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:11:in `render_with_haml'
rails_admin (0.1.2) app/views/layouts/rails_admin/application.html.haml:27:in `_c___uby____lib_ruby_gems_______gems_rails_admin_______app_views_layouts_rails_admin_application_html_haml___191072136_5393304'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
remotipart (1.0.2) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:8:in `render'
rails_admin (0.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/actions/index.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in '
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
rails_admin (0.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/actions/index.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in '
(eval):8:in `instance_eval'
(eval):8:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:469:in `_run__375825897__process_action__876887233__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
rack-pjax (0.6.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
remotipart (1.0.2) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__979894838__call__1042350755__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

### gems used

```
$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.8)
  * actionpack (3.2.8)
  * activemodel (3.2.8)
  * activerecord (3.2.8)
  * activeresource (3.2.8)
  * activesupport (3.2.8)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
  * bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.1)
  * builder (3.0.2)
  * bundler (1.1.4)
  * carrierwave (0.7.0)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
  * devise (2.0.4)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * font-awesome-sass-rails (2.0.0.0)
  * haml (3.1.7)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.1)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.1.2)
  * jquery-ui-rails (2.0.2)
  * json (1.7.5)
  * kaminari (0.14.1)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.19)
  * multi_json (1.3.6)
  * mysql (2.8.1)
  * nested_form (0.2.3)
  * nokogiri (1.5.5)
  * orm_adapter (0.0.7)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-pjax (0.6.0)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.8)
  * rails_admin (0.1.2)
  * railties (3.2.8)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * remotipart (1.0.2)
  * sass (3.2.1)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.6)
  * thor (0.16.0)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.7 ad1b849)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
  * uglifier (1.3.0)
  * warden (1.1.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem, by using the msql2 gem instead of the mysql gem:

> "Notice that I am using the mysql2 adapter instead of mysql. At this point (Feb 2011) the mysql gem is NOT encoding aware. Replace mysql with mysql2 in your Gemfile and run bundle."[[see rails-utf-8-and-heroku]](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.de/2011/02/rails-utf-8-and-heroku.html)